# Help to Interpret Apple crash report

Tags: iphone, ios4, crash, crash-reports

I can't reproduce the error I'm getting in the Apple crash reports. I have 4 apps using the same codebase already approved and now I have had 2 rejected with the same errors that I have never come across.

Below is the crash report that I got back from my Apple Review.
Below that again is the line indicated as the error in my App Delegate.
I'm looking at the system calls round the error at the moment in case they shed some light for me.

```
Incident Identifier: XXXXXX
CrashReporter Key:   XXXXXX
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         XXXX [120]
Path:            XXXX
Identifier:      XXXX
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       XXXX
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.1 (8B117)
Report Version:  XXXX

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00078ac8 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00078ab8 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00078aaa raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008d03a abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00044a20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00005958 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042df2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042e46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042f16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00004838 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000a167c -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 96
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000491d2 ___forwarding___ + 502
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00048f88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 40
13  XXX                         0x00002a02 -[XXX application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (XXXAppDelegate.m:94)
14  UIKit                           0x0000e47a -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 766
15  UIKit                           0x000049e0 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 200
16  UIKit                           0x0005dfd6 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1390
17  UIKit                           0x0005d8fa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
18  UIKit                           0x0005d330 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5104
19  GraphicsServices                0x00005044 PurpleEventCallback + 660
20  CoreFoundation                  0x00034cdc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00034ca0 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
22  CoreFoundation                  0x00027566 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
25  UIKit                           0x000040fc -[UIApplication _run] + 364
26  UIKit                           0x00002128 UIApplicationMain + 664
27  XXX                         0x00002154 main (main.m:14)
28  XXX                         0x00002124 start + 32
```

Code in the AppDelegate:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = favNavController.viewControllers;
FavouritesViewController *favouritesView = (FavouritesViewController*)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; <-- Line indicated in crash report
```

I cannot reproduce this. Any insight or advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like "favNavController.viewControllers" is not an NSArray - therefore you are getting "Unrecognized Selector" when trying to do a "objectAtIndex".

Did you note that it looks like the app was being launched in response to a URL? (OpenWithURL)?

I don't know if this takes your code through a different initialization path - which wasn't complete at this time.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. The OpenWithUrl is not something I'm familiar with, and will look at now, to be honest its not part of my design to have my app launched in reponse to a URL. My understanding is that this is like launching the Google maps app with a latitude/longitude as parameters or dialling a phone number using tel:555-709-7654 type affair?

Comment: Okay, I've been try to glean some information about the system calls referring to a URL in the crash report but I'm not learning much.   Are calls to callInitializationDelegatesForURL and _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden: a different way launching the app or some such? Sorry but I'm struggling with this... :(

Comment: I intentionally called caused an unrecognized selector exception at the line inidicated,"favNavController.viewControllers". And reproduced the error exactly. D'oh moment as to why I hadn't thought to do it sooner. So now I have to understand why the viewControllers array is causing the trouble. It is all set up via nib files so thought it would be taken care of.

Comment: Hmmmmmm. My app is Tabbar base, with each tab having it's own navigation controller. In IB the main view controller for each of the navigation controllers  has a type associated with it in the inspector. For me the type was shown in the 'Type' column of main nib summary window. But on opening the controller attributes there was no nib specified. This mean when you see the template interface it did not show "View loaded from viewControllerName". I think this is why the FavNavController.viewControllers was causing the selector not recognised.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct Brad just to note that the "launched in response to a URL? (OpenWithURL)?" bit seems just to be some internal thing and not a URL in my understanding. I'll try and resubmit and hope it gets through as I can't find anything else. Strange that this never came up on my test devices or the simulator though :(

Comment: Not sure I've solved it after all. I submit a response here when I have a rejection/acceptance from apple.